# Trigger an event on specific slide - Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Ok, so I need to trigger an event when specific (let's say number 2) slide is displayed. I've checked this function:

```
$('#myCarousel').bind('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    console.log($(this));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9fwuq/380/

but in the console there's no information what slide is displayed. How to get the actuall number of slide? Anyone can help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this event instead and following logic: {maybe better way, check the DOC}

```
$('#myCarousel').bind('slid', function (e) {
    var index = $(e.target).find(".active").index();
    if(index === 1) //  (2 - 1) index is zero based
        alert('slide2 displayed!');
})
```

;

### -DEMO-

Comment: Thank you, it works perfect, but like I've mentioned in the comment below, I thought bootstrap provides detailed info by default, so I don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

see this. http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/9fwuq/382/

```
   var x=0;
    $('#myCarousel').bind('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {

        if(x%3==0)
        {
            console.log('slide number');

// trigger you event here
        }
        x++;
    });
```

you just need to put a condition to check the number of current slide. in the example given above, i am checking each time the first slide.[assuming the count starts from 00].

Comment: That make sense, but I thought I can get some more info (by default) calling this event. In this case I also need to count using js how many slides the slider contains to reset the counter each time it reaches total. But anyway, your answer is pretty fine and explains what I wanted, so thank you very much. :)